# disabling mdi child maximizing when activating by clicking on title bar

Tags: c#, mdi

I have an MDI form that I open multiple child windows into. I have noticed that if I click the title bar of an a child form that is not the active mdi child, that that child becomes actived and maximizes. This behavior does NOT happen when I click the unactivated child in a place other than the title bar. How can I disable the maximizing in this case? I still want to be able to maximize the form using the maximize button on the title bar. It would also be nice to be able to maximize a form when double-clicking the title bar (just not single-clicking).
I have found this routine to be causing the problem, but not sure how. This method is called whenever when an mdi child's activated event is called. This specific statement is causing the problem: "if (dv.Disk.IsOS9)"

```
    private void UpdateDiskMenu()
    {
        if (this.ActiveMdiChild == null)
        {
            diskToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            diskToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            DiskViewer dv = (DiskViewer)this.ActiveMdiChild;

            if (dv.Disk.IsOS9) // <----- Problem occurs here.
            {
                //if (((OS9Format)dv.Disk).BootstrapLSN > 0)
                //    bootstrapToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                //else
                //    bootstrapToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried to trap it using the overridable WndProc method, but the maximizing occurs BEFORE WndProc fires.

Comment: This is not normal.  A child only maximizes if the previous child was maximized.  But you could not click it if that was the case.  Double-clicking certainly maximizes, you would have mentioned that.  The only logical explanation is that this is done by your code.  Pretty common to write that kind of code, maybe you didn't write it?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the code. But no where in my code have I set it to maximize any form.

Comment: If I single step through the routine, the problem does not occur. It only happens during normal runtime.

Comment: Specifically, when calling the IsOS9 property of dv.Disk. that property just runs a method that validates the dv.Disk's data. that method has absolutely nothing to do with any windows form.

Comment: I was able to get around the issue by having a public field in the DiskViewer called isOS9, and setting that field during the form's constructor, then testing that field instead of calling the IsOS9 property directly.